# Is a comma still required between "said" and a quote if no one actually says anything?

Tags: punctuation

For example

He gave me a look that said "Don't you dare."

Should a comma still be placed after said?

Comment: This situation is different from the one that uses the rule of "comma after said". Do not use a comma here.

Comment: ... The rule of "comma after said" has been relegated to a style-choice anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Larry Trask had [strong views](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/quotes/marks) on this, whether the person described actually says anything or not:

> Now notice something else which is very important: a quotation is set
>   off by quotation marks and nothing else. A sentence containing a
>   quotation is punctuated exactly like any other sentence apart from the
>   addition of the quotation marks. You should not insert additional
>   punctuation marks into the sentence merely to warn the reader that a
>   quotation is coming up: that's what the quotation marks are for. Hence
>   the first two of the following are bad style, and the third one is
>   wrong:
>
> *President Nixon declared, "I am not a crook."
>
> *President Nixon declared: "I am not a crook."
>
> *President Nixon declared:- "I am not a crook."
>
> The comma and the colon in the first two are completely pointless, while the startling
>   arsenal of punctuation in the third is grotesque. (Remember, a colon
>   can never be followed by a hyphen or a dash.) Here is the sentence
>   with proper punctuation:
>
> President Nixon declared "I am not a crook."
>
> Adding more dots and squiggles to this perfectly clear sentence would
>   do absolutely nothing to improve it. No punctuation mark should be
>   used if it is not necessary.

I have much sympathy with this approach. Unless you have to follow the requirements of a house style guide, I’d omit the comma, both in the case you describe, and when actual speech is quoted.

Comment: I usually use zero punctuation before a quote, but (and I think Trask isn't proscribing this) would on occasion choose a comma or even a colon if I felt the sentence worked better with one. It doesn't in this instance. // Nice descriptor for :- :)

Answer (score 1):

I checked a number of online publications (by Googling for `"a look that said"` plus a `site:`-expression to restrict the search to a specific domain), and found some variation:

- *The New York Times*, *The New Yorker*, and *The Washington Post* generally use a comma, as for ordinary reported speech. [[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3anytimes.com+%22a+look+that+said%22)][[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3anewyorker.com+%22a+look+that+said%22)][[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3awashingtonpost.com+%22a+look+that+said%22)]
- *The Guardian* generally uses a colon, as for normal reported speech. [[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3atheguardian.com+%22a+look+that+said%22)]
- *The Times* and *The Sunday Times* did not have enough examples to tell.

However, I found many examples where the quotation marks were eliminated. When that was done, the punctuation mark of choice was much more likely to be a colon.

Answer (score 1):

He gave me a look that said *don't you dare.*

Why not italicize it?